# Use createOracleArray with a prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I need to query data from an Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition through JDBC using read-only access.
I am using Quarkus (https://quarkus.io) and an AgroalDataSource (ds in the following).

I have a the following code (try/catch omitted for readability):

```
var oSql = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE tag in (?)";
var connection = ds.getConnection();
var oracleCon = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
var prepStmt = connection.preparedStatement(oSql);

// here I would like to set the ? to a list and I found createOracleArray, but it needs a first parameter. How do I create it?
var arr = oracleCon.createOracleArray("???", new String[] {"tag1", "tag2"});
prepStmt.setArray(1, arr);
```

Comment: You actually can't use a set in a bind variable. What would be the problem with constructing the statement `String`-wise?

Comment: Using string concatenation leads to the security issue of sql injections

Comment: That's not the case here (unless you're allowing external passing of statements/queries into your code and you're not showing us…)

Comment: The strings are inputs from other systems/users, this was easier to explain

Comment: If it's just the set parameters, then injection shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's SQL supports two forms of IN operator

- in values like `IN (1, 2, 3, :4)` . The the values are scalar, can be constants or bind variables and their amount MUST be defied/known before SQL is executed.
- in subquery `IN (select single_column from ...)`. In this case there is a subquery returning a cursor.

Neither of options is applicable for you directly.
If you have a luck and JDBC drivers support it, you can use `TABLE()` operator to convert a collection into in memory table:

```
SELECT * from example where tag in (select * from TABLE(?));
```

The `TABLE` operator will convert collection into a table and subquery will return a cursor.

See this [example](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/532650/using-in-and-table-operators-via-jdbc):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

/**
 * Tests an SQL query that uses the IN operator and the TABLE keyword.
 * The TABLE keyword transforms a PL/SQL collection into a regular table.
 * Hence a query can use the IN operator with a PL/SQL collection.
 * A PL/SQL collection maps to a java array.
 * Hence you can execute a query using a <code>PreparedStatement</code> and an
 * array as the parameter value.
 * Note, however, that the PL/SQL collection type <em>must</em> be a database
 * named type, one that is defined using the CREATE TYPE [DDL] statement.
 */
public class SqlQuery {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection c = null;
    Object[] oa = new Object[3];
    oa[0] = new BigDecimal("9712061");
    oa[1] = new BigDecimal("9712062");
    oa[2] = new BigDecimal("9712063");
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "select ENAME " +
                   "from EMP " +
                  "where EMPNO in (" +
                                  "select * " +
                                    "from table(?)" +
                                 ")";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//localhost:1521/orcl";
    try {
      OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
      ods.setURL(url);
      c = ods.getConnection();
      ArrayDescriptor ad = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
                                                       "<nested table type name>",
                                                       c);
      ARRAY a = new ARRAY(ad, c, (Object) oa);
      ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setArray(1, a);

      /* overcome deprecated ArrayDescriptor 
      int[] values = { 1, 2, 3 };
      Array javaSqlArray = ((OracleConnection) conn).createOracleArray("<nested table type name>", values);
      ps.setObject(1, javaSqlArray);
      */
      rs = ps.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
      }
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
      x.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      if (rs != null) {
        try {
          rs.close();
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
          System.err.println("Failed to close result set.");
          x.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (ps != null) {
        try {
          ps.close();
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
          System.err.println("Failed to close statement.");
          x.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (c != null) {
        try {
          c.close();
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
          System.err.println("Failed to close database connection.");
          x.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** @gouessej, I did check Metalink notes (Doc ID 2563257.1) and (Doc ID 1364193.1) and now it looks like Oracle JDBC **will not** support Connection.createArrayOf.

```
int[] intArray = { 5, 7, 9};
oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor aDescriptor = new oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor("<user>.TYPE1", connection);
oracle.sql.ARRAY array = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(aDescriptor, connection, intArray);

Should be changed to:

int[] intArray = { 5, 7, 9};
java.sql.Array array = (OracleConnection)connection.createOracleArray("<user>.TYPE1", intArray);
```

> NOTE:Oracle does not support anonymous array types and so does not
> support the standard Connection.createArrayOf method.

I'd say the reason is that PL/SQL is inspired by ADA and ADA is strongly typed language. Oracle does not have generic type for array of Strings, users have to create a named type for each use of non-scalar type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the ArrayDescriptor is deprecated https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor.html

Comment: Yes that part is tricky, there were times when JDBC standard was intentionally very minimalistic and did not support vector values and other stuff. Oracle had to use proprietary extensions. Nowadays JDBC standard has evolved and proprietary extensions are being  replaced with new standards.

Comment: Moreover createOracleArray might also be deprecated, replaced with createArrayOf (but not supported by certain JDBC driver versions).

Comment: @ibre5041 createArrayOf() is still unsupported by Oracle 19, it throws a java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.